How to set the path to images if they are to be rendered from server side in a golem shiny app?
Goal
In a shiny app, render multiple ggplot plots with images as facet labels.
You can see the complete source code here.
Details and Problem
I want to create two plots both of which use the same images. In a normal shiny app, I can read the images in global.R and then use them to create plots in the server part.
In the golem framework, I created a R/global.R file with this code:
labels_flowers <- c(
  setosa     = paste0("<img src='", "inst/app/www", "/", "setosa.jpg' width='100'/>"),
  versicolor = paste0("<img src='", "inst/app/www", "/", "versicolor.jpg' width='100'/>"),
  virginica  = paste0("<img src='", "inst/app/www", "/", "virginica.jpg' width='100'/>")
)

And then I used them in two modules.
Module example
Consider this module:
#' plot UI Function
#'
#' @description A shiny Module.
#'
#' @param id,input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'
#' @noRd
#'
#' @import shiny
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import ggtext
mod_plot_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotOutput(ns("myplot"))
  )
}

#' plot Server Functions
#'
#' @noRd
mod_plot_server <- function(id, data){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    output$myplot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(data = data()) +
        geom_histogram(aes(Sepal.Length)) +
        facet_wrap(~ Species, labeller = as_labeller(labels_flowers)) +
        theme(strip.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 20))
    })
  })
}

The app_ui.R and app_server.R use the modules as:
app_ui.R
#' The application User-Interface
#'
#' @param request Internal parameter for `{shiny}`.
#'     DO NOT REMOVE.
#' @import shiny
#' @noRd
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    # Leave this function for adding external resources
    golem_add_external_resources(),
    # Your application UI logic
    fluidPage(
      h1("example"),
      mod_plot_ui("plot1"),
      mod_plot2_ui("plot2")
    )
  )
}

#' Add external Resources to the Application
#'
#' This function is internally used to add external
#' resources inside the Shiny application.
#'
#' @import shiny
#' @importFrom golem add_resource_path activate_js favicon bundle_resources
#' @noRd
golem_add_external_resources <- function() {
  add_resource_path(
    "www",
    app_sys("app/www")
  )

  tags$head(
    favicon(),
    bundle_resources(
      path = app_sys("app/www"),
      app_title = "example"
    )
    # Add here other external resources
    # for example, you can add shinyalert::useShinyalert()
  )
}

app_server.R
#' The application server-side
#'
#' @param input,output,session Internal parameters for {shiny}.
#'     DO NOT REMOVE.
#' @import shiny
#' @import ggplot2
#' @import ggtext
#' @noRd
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {

  df_iris <- reactive(iris)

  mod_plot_server("plot1", df_iris)
  mod_plot2_server("plot2", df_iris)

}

App works locally and on shinyapps but not on Google Cloud Run
App works fine locally and on shinyapps. But the app deployed via Dockerfile on Google Cloud Run throws error:

What do I change to make sure that the app works fine on Google Cloud Run?

I'm not familiar with golem but it sounds like you need to use app_sys() https://engineering-shiny.org/golem.html#instappwww

@smartse app_sys is indeed what I needed. Thank you.
